# Pull Table from Webpage Behind Login Using Requests?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I'm practicing with the Requests library, and I've run into an issue trying to grab a table from a webpage after first logging in using a session.

I'm trying to grab the "Trading history" tables from pages like [this](https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/811921?source=Site%20Signals%20MT5%20Table#!tab=history), but in order to see the actual trades in the table, you have to be logged in to the page first. I have login credentials and I've tried using the code below, and it appears to log in fine with a 200 status code, however when I attempt to pull the table from that URL after that, the output of my request still says I need to login to view the table.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
import requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = "https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login"
payload = {
    'Login': "MY_USERNAME_HERE",
    'Password': "MY_PASSWORD_HERE"
}
table_url = "https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/811921?source=Site+Signals+MT5+Table#!tab=history"

# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post(login_url, data=payload)
print(s.status_code)

# Navigate to the next page and scrape the data
html = session.get(table_url)
print(html.status_code)

# Get the soup of the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the table
table = soup.find("div", {"id": "tab_content_history"})
table = table.find("div", {"class": "tab__content__item"})
print(table)
```

The output of my prints look like this:

```
200
200
<div class="tab__content__item">
<div class="need-auth">To see trades in realtime, please <strong><a href="https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login">log in</a></strong> or <strong><a href="https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_register">register</a></strong></div>
</div>
```

`Login` and `Password` are the `name`'s of the login elements. What else could I be missing in getting the session to login correctly? I don't see any tokens that need to be added to the payload, but I could be wrong as well. What else could I try? If you don't have login to this site it's fine, just looking for other ideas on what to try if you have experience using request sessions. You can review the page inspection of the login form from [this page](https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login). I recognize web scraping is NOT allowed, I'm just using this site as a public example as I would need to use similar logic for a work project. Thanks!

Comment: I would try to use the mechanize library. It let's you manipulate the web page as if you were using a browser. That way you could simulate entering user name and password and clicking the login button, without having to figure out how exactly the page's login service works.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
import random
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

user_agent_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11.5; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_5_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
]

data = []

# set url
url = 'https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/811921?source=Site+Signals+MT5+Table#!tab=history'

# call open browser function
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
userAgent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

# login to website
sign_in_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log in')
sign_in_link.click()

username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'Login')))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'Password')))
username.send_keys('your_username')
password.send_keys('your_password')

driver.find_element_by_id("loginSubmit").click()
time.sleep(2)

innerHTML = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")

# Find the table
table = soup.find("div", {"id": "tab_content_history"})
table = table.find("div", {"class": "tab__content__item"})
table_body = table.find('tbody')

rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols])


df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
df.columns = ['Time', 'Type', 'Volume', 'Symbol', 'Price', 'Time', 'Price', 'Commission', 'Swap', 'Profit']
print(df)

driver.quit()
```

---

**Output:**

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 93.0.4577
Get LATEST driver version for 93.0.4577
Driver [/home/user/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/93.0.4577.63/chromedriver] found in cache
                Time  Type Volume  Symbol    Price              Time    Price Commission   Swap Profit
0   2021.09.17 09:56   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89502  2021.09.17 14:54  0.89623      -0.12          2.85
1   2021.09.17 02:58   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89570  2021.09.17 06:36  0.89625      -0.12          1.30
2   2021.09.16 14:17   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89626  2021.09.16 19:03  0.89749      -0.12          2.91
3   2021.09.16 12:48   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89714  2021.09.16 19:03  0.89749      -0.12          0.83
4   2021.09.16 04:56  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89857  2021.09.16 12:38  0.89777      -0.12          1.90
5   2021.09.16 01:31  Sell   0.03  AUDCAD  0.92665  2021.09.16 02:11  0.92650      -0.12          0.36
6   2021.09.15 14:32   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89842  2021.09.15 22:45  0.89896      -0.12  -0.51   1.28
7   2021.09.15 12:49   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89995  2021.09.15 22:45  0.89896      -0.12  -0.51  -2.35
8   2021.09.15 04:16  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89992  2021.09.15 12:35  0.89977      -0.12          0.35
9   2021.09.14 13:07  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.90053  2021.09.14 14:12  0.90043      -0.12          0.24
10  2021.09.14 08:08  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.90040  2021.09.14 10:16  0.89976      -0.12          1.52
11  2021.09.13 07:44  Sell   0.02  NZDCAD  0.90165  2021.09.13 09:42  0.90094      -0.08          1.12
12  2021.09.13 01:10  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.90096  2021.09.13 06:30  0.89982      -0.12          2.70
13  2021.09.10 12:32  Sell   0.05  NZDCAD  0.90067  2021.09.10 12:58  0.90042      -0.20          0.99
14  2021.09.09 07:50  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.90334  2021.09.09 16:59  0.89919      -0.12          9.86
15  2021.09.08 11:16  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.90021  2021.09.09 16:59  0.89920      -0.12  -0.30   2.40
16  2021.09.07 16:20  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89673  2021.09.09 16:59  0.89914      -0.12  -0.40  -5.72
17  2021.09.07 11:07  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89637  2021.09.07 13:54  0.89522      -0.12          2.74
18  2021.09.03 16:54  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89541  2021.09.06 14:26  0.89438      -0.12  -0.10   2.47
19  2021.09.03 14:03  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89447  2021.09.03 14:49  0.89342      -0.12          2.52
20  2021.09.02 12:52  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89466  2021.09.02 16:43  0.89307      -0.12          3.80
21  2021.09.02 09:45  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89297  2021.09.02 16:43  0.89307      -0.12         -0.24
22  2021.09.02 06:21  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.89244  2021.09.02 08:00  0.89140      -0.12          2.48
23  2021.08.31 11:29  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88831  2021.09.01 12:40  0.88704      -0.12  -0.10   3.03
24  2021.08.31 06:32  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88773  2021.09.01 12:40  0.88707      -0.12  -0.10   1.57
25  2021.08.31 03:02  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88654  2021.09.01 12:40  0.88707      -0.12  -0.10  -1.26
26  2021.08.30 02:31  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88391  2021.08.30 06:12  0.88335      -0.12          1.33
27  2021.08.27 16:47  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88475  2021.08.29 22:04  0.88437      -0.12  -0.10   0.90
28  2021.08.27 12:31  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88189  2021.08.27 13:22  0.88120      -0.12          1.63
29  2021.08.27 01:10  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88193  2021.08.27 03:31  0.88013      -0.12          4.26
30  2021.08.26 15:55  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88039  2021.08.27 03:31  0.88013      -0.12  -0.10   0.61
31  2021.08.26 14:42  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87928  2021.08.27 03:31  0.88013      -0.12  -0.10  -2.01
32  2021.08.25 15:13  Sell   0.02  NZDCAD  0.87859  2021.08.26 09:05  0.87712      -0.08  -0.20   2.33
33  2021.08.25 10:09  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87745  2021.08.26 09:05  0.87710      -0.12  -0.30   0.83
34  2021.08.25 07:58  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87632  2021.08.26 09:05  0.87712      -0.12  -0.30  -1.90
35  2021.08.24 08:45  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87599  2021.08.24 17:02  0.87533      -0.12          1.57
36  2021.08.23 04:20   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87396  2021.08.23 12:44  0.87461      -0.12          1.53
37  2021.08.20 13:20  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87990  2021.08.20 13:47  0.87896      -0.12          2.19
38  2021.08.20 12:08  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.88049  2021.08.20 13:16  0.88043      -0.12          0.14
39  2021.08.20 04:32  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87886  2021.08.20 06:40  0.87781      -0.12          2.45
40  2021.08.18 13:30   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.86860  2021.08.18 15:31  0.87046      -0.12          4.42
41  2021.08.18 12:35   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87085  2021.08.18 15:31  0.87049      -0.12         -0.85
42  2021.08.18 11:37  Sell   0.03  AUDNZD  1.05070  2021.08.18 12:00  1.05023      -0.12          0.97
43  2021.08.18 10:14   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87009  2021.08.18 11:28  0.87071      -0.12          1.47
44  2021.08.18 07:11   Buy   0.03  EURUSD  1.17214  2021.08.18 07:39  1.17277      -0.18          1.89
45  2021.08.18 05:13   Buy   0.03  EURUSD  1.17161  2021.08.18 06:59  1.17172      -0.18          0.33
46  2021.08.18 05:01  Sell   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87438  2021.08.18 05:55  0.87325      -0.12          2.69
47  2021.08.17 12:59   Buy   0.03  NZDCAD  0.87254  2021.08.18 01:13  0.87490      -0.12  -0.17   5.61
```

---

> #### Make sure have selenium and BeautifulSoup installed in your system

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, however I wanted to figure this out using request.sessions, not using Selenium....

Comment: I tried all possible ways with request but couldn't able to do that. Later implement selenium solution. :)